How can I use the Google Sheets API to append some data to a new row in a Google Sheet?
I have a Stats project where we need to collect at least 30 data points each from 4 groups on an online form that I made. Pipedream would be my ideal choice for this, except I only get 100 free credits (workflow runs) per month and I've already used like 60 for testing. I tried looking into the Google Sheets API documentation, as well as gapi, but I can't make anything out.
I have an online form that will send a POST request with the data in the request body as JSON to a server. There are 8 different data points, which each go into their respective columns in the sheet (A-G).
Would Firebase be good thing to use here? Some other automation tool? The one thing that I know will work is sending serialized JSON to a Google Chat webhook, but that hardly seems adequate.
I would really like to directly work with Google Sheets, but I can pretty much work with any method that remotely stores data which I can parse on my end.
Overall, I need some way to append arbitrary data to a row in a Google Sheet.

google forms would be great if we didn't need to randomize the questions and their contents

another idea I had was making a bunch of pipedream alt accounts, each with a copy of the workflow, and then randomizing which url gets POSTed
...
idk I'm kinda out of ideas

Sheetdb worked for me (not affiliated). It has a really nice REST API, and you have 500 free requests per month.
You can append a row of data to a Google Sheet like so:

fetch('https://sheetdb.io/api/v1/58f61be4dda40' /* their testing Sheet */, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        data: [
            {
                'id': "INCREMENT", // finds the highest element in the column and adds 1
                'name': "Mark",
                'age': 18
            }
        ]
    })
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));

...assuming id, name, and age are all string cells in row 1.

If you want to recommend your own product or website, there are some guidelines in place for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Please [edit] your post to explicitly state your affiliation. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well). After you have edited your post, you may flag it as "In need of moderator intervention" to request a reevaluation.
